# Expect: How to iterate over files in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, expect

The following is a bash script which iterate over .csv files within a directory. The question is, I now have an expect script `#!/usr/bin/expect`  where I want to use the same for loop. How could I achieve that?

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in /path/*.csv
do
echo $f
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would write:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
foreach f [glob /path/*.csv] {
    puts $f
}
```

Expect is an extension of Tcl. In addition to the `expect` man page, a link to the Tcl command documentation will be helpful: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm